# sql duplicate records with changes

Tags: sql

I need to duplicate some records in a table changing one field.

At first i did it in php, but it took too much time. So, the obvious solution is using sql query.

Say, we have a table CP with Primary key `id`, foreign key `r_id` and `data1` and `data2`.
I need to copy all the records with `r_id`=666 for example but change  value `r_id` to 777.

I found this http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/993807-how-create-duplicate-rows.html but value is not changed there. So, may be INSERT INTO, SELECT and UPDATE should be used together somehow.

Can't find the solution. Please help.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle...)? SQL is merely a  structured query language. How is `id` column is defined? Is it `auto_increment` (if it's MySQL) / `identity` (if it's SQL Server)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [INSERT INTO](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

```
INSERT INTO cp (r_id, data1, data2)
SELECT  777, data1, data2
FROM    cp
WHERE   cp.r_id = 666;
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/375775/1/0)

assuming you have autogenerated id and MYSQL